# Apache Web Server weird behaviour

Tags: apache

We have our website on apache webserver. Website is written in php coding and our server is a virtual server and It is running properly. Our main problem is that,our product uploader team cannot upload the products to our web server during the time 5.30 pm to 6.00 pm.Before 5.30 and after 6.00 pm they dont have any problem in uploading. When its 5.30pm,the uploading page is just loading and nothing happens. So we have to wait for half an hour daily.We have centos 6 in the server and apache version is 2.2.15.I have enabled the server-status option in apache and monitor continuously, but found no error. I also checked the httpd error and access log,but nothing serious log is found,just some php notice.But we can access the website at any time,but cannot upload in websites from 5.30 to 6.00 pm.If you could suggest me what should I do,i will be grateful to you. Thanks in advance.

In server status number of W is increased during 5.30 to 6 Pm duration and after that number of W is reduced. Also I checked our Mysql database from phpmyadmin, it shows something like SLEEP. Help..

Well I have somehow fixed this problem...I increase the innodb buffer pool size 
innodb_buffer_pool = 500MB. My data size is almost 420MB, previously our innodb_buffer_pool size was 128MB.After changing the size, there is no problem till now...May be I solved the problem :)

Comment: This doesn't sound like something we can diagnose here for you. Could be anything. Some process spins up during that time and blocks something important. Some cron job from another system is making calls during that window and blocks something important. There's a hard coded block in the upload script for those times...

Comment: Thank you deceze...i will try to find what is causing this problem